# Using the REST API to view an External Column in a list (Not an External List)

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, bcs, external-data-column

I have done some research and it does seem possible to read an External List, but I am trying to read an External **Column** within a regular list. How can I use the REST API to view an External **Column** (not an External List)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer - use this REST scheme: http[s]://sitename/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Sample Data List')/Items?$select=internalNameOfColumn